# Data Import deletes any VIEWS that were previously created

Tags: postgresql, view

I've created VIEWS in PostgreSQL recently. I run on a daily basis an import script that ingested the DB with new data by dropping all schemas and tables and then re-creating the schemas and importing the data.
Is there a way of keeping the created VIEWS in the DB?
I didn't realize that the VIEWS would be deleted as well. The reason why they are not recreated as the Schemas is that the script reads from a source DB while the VIEWS are created on the target.
Are there other ways of circumventing this? Or any workarounds for re-using VIEWS or similar in this methodology - of dropping the schemas every day.

Thanks

Comment: What about *changing the script* and making it create the views?

Comment: That seems like the only way of re-creating the views,yeah.